# ValueError: signal only works in main thread error while connecting to BIG IP appliance

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

**below is the flask app module:**

```
@app.route('/service', methods=['POST'])
def service():
    postData = request.data

    try:
        mgmt = src.connect();
        src.execute(mgmt);
        return "request completed"
    except Exception, e:
        return ("Exception occured" + str(e));



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5050, debug=True, use_reloader=False)
    #app.run(port=5050);
```

**Below is the module making connection:**

```
def connect():

    try:
        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        config.readfp(open(r'./config.ini'))
        cipher_suite = Fernet(config.get('connection','token')) 
        decoded_pass = cipher_suite.decrypt(config.get('connection','hash'))
        # Connect to the BIG-IP device.
        mgmt = ManagementRoot(config.get('connection','ipaddr'),config.get('connection','user'),decoded_pass)
        return mgmt;    
    except Exception as e:
        l
        log.error(e)
        raise e;
```

I am not starting a new thread but, it throws **ValueError: signal only works in main thread** while connecting to BIG IP in the below step as shown in the above

```
mgmt = ManagementRoot(config.get('connection','ipaddr'),config.get('connection','user'),decoded_pass)
```

I am using the f5-sdk in which signal has been used as below:

```
        if HAS_SIGNAL:
            signal.signal(SIGALRM, timeout_handler) ## this line throws the error
            signal.alarm(int(self.args['timeout']))
            response = connect.get(base_uri)
            signal.alarm(0)
        else:
            response = connect.get(base_uri)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, UNIX signals can't be set up from threads other than the main thread.

Looks like the F5 SDK is using signals for connection timeouts (which is a bit silly, but so it is).

You can work around this by explicitly telling the SDK you don't have signals available by [setting the flag](https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-common-python/blob/9a90eb5f2db30d450991cd636d43a94070fda14f/f5/bigip/__init__.py#L26-L31) early in your app:

```
from f5 import bigip
bigip.HAS_SIGNAL = False  # Override autodetection
```

Naturally the other workaround is to connect from the main thread, but I assume that's not something you want to do for whichever reason :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I have come across other workaround which I will post in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the below piece of code in my flask app module instead of the commented one to make it work.

```
# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     app.run(port=5050, debug=True, use_reloader=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
    from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
    from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

    http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
    http_server.listen(5050)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```